# how to pass argument to fact and find remaining argument in it

Tags: prolog

i am trying to make expert system in prolog using facts,i have defined some facts and try to diagnose those facts from user input,but when passing arguments ,it is not giving the value,not the remaining argument

***these are the facts***

```
diseas(chikungunya,fever,jointpain,headache,musclepain,jointswelling).
diseas(dengue,fever,eyespain,headache,musclepain,nausea).
diseas(malaria,fever,chestpain,headache,musclepain,nausea).
diseas(dyria,fever,abdominalpain,_,abdominalpain,bloodinstool).
```

***this is the rule***

```
question1:-write('do you have fever?,1.yes or 2.no'),nl,read(A),(A='yes'->Ch1='fever';(A='no'->Ch1='nofever')),display(Ch1),
    write('which pain do you feel?'),nl,write('1.jointpain,2.eyespain,3.chestpain,4.abdominalpain'),read(B),(B=1->Ch2='jointpain';(B=2->Ch2='eyespain';(B=3->Ch2='chestpain';(B=4->Ch2='abdominalpain')))),
    write('do you have headache?,1.yes or 2.no'),nl,read(C),(C='yes'->Ch3='headache';(C='no'->Ch3='noheadache')),display(Ch3),
    write('inw hich part of body do you feel pain?'),nl,write('1.musclepain,2.abdominalpain'),read(D),(D=1->Ch4='musclepain';(D=2->Ch4='abdominalpain')),
    write('any other issue'),nl,write('1.jointswelling,2.nausea,3.bloodinstool'),read(E),(E=1->Ch5='jointswelling';(E=2->Ch5='nausea';(E=3->ch5='bloodinstool'))),write(diseas(X,Ch1,Ch2,Ch3,Ch4,Ch5)).
```

i expect , `diseas(dengue,fever,eyespain,headache,muscularpain)`,but it is giving `diseas(_2345.fever,eyespain,headache,muscularpain)`

Comment: You say "it is not giving the value,not the remaining argument". It would be helpful to clarify what you expect, and also what you've tried to get the desired result.

Comment: disease() fact have 6 arguments in total,out of which first one is the name of disease,while others are symptoms,my code is asking other 5 arguments from user and returning them to 2nd,3rd,4th,5th and 6th argument ,while the first argument is empty variable which should return the name of disease according to other arguments passed.